# kubernetes flannel daemonset not starting (Clean Ubuntu 16 and 18)

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I just installed kubernetes on a clean ubuntu machine following this steps (from linux academy):

As root:

```
apt install -y docker.io

cat << EOF >/etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
}
EOF

curl -s http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -

cat << EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF

apt update -y

apt install -y kubeadm kubectl kubelet
```

Then as regular user initialize kubernetes:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

At this moment the node is set but not ready yet so I run yml for flannel to create the daemon, services and pods:

```
sudo kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.9.1/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

But, I can't see the pods and the daemonsets got desired pods = 0

No pods (coredns are waiting for flannel setup):

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-j2rbn                             0/1     Pending   0          2m25s
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-lqhrj                             0/1     Pending   0          2m25s
kube-system   etcd-webdriver1.mylabserver.com                      1/1     Running   0          118s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-webdriver1.mylabserver.com            1/1     Running   0          94s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-webdriver1.mylabserver.com   1/1     Running   0          89s
kube-system   kube-proxy-fzh97                                     1/1     Running   0          2m25s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-webdriver1.mylabserver.com            1/1     Running   0          90s
```

And the deamonset

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                   AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds   0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64   3m49s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy        1         1         1       1            1           <none>                          48m
```

Any help how can I debug this issue?

Comment: describe the resource `kubectl describe ds/kube-flannel-ds -n kube-system`

Comment: provide pod logs kubectl logs coredns-576cbf47c7-j2rbn  -n kube-system --v=9. Just reproduced on ubuntu 16  - works fine.Try to recreate and use latest flannel version kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.10.0/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

Comment: it seems the version of flannel v0.9.1 doesn't work with the latest version or kubernetes, I will do some test and come back with (possibly) an answer

Comment: Flannel v0.9.1 and v0.10.0 both have the same issue with the latest k8s: the daemonset tolerations in their default configurations restrict them from being scheduled. Modify the tolerations (as mentioned in my answer below...grin) and you'll be up and running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration file you're applying to create the flannel resources includes daemonset tolerations that are too restrictive, so the pods won't be scheduled on any nodes. Add a catchall scheduling toleration to the flannel daemonset (like the [canal configuration](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/canal/canal.yaml) does) and they'll be scheduled as expected. You can do this in 2 ways:

(1) Patch your existing configuration

```
kubectl patch daemonset kube-flannel-ds \
  --namespace=kube-system \
  --patch='{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"tolerations":[{"key": "node-role.kubernetes.io/master", "operator": "Exists", "effect": "NoSchedule"},{"effect":"NoSchedule","operator":"Exists"}]}}}}'
```

(2) Modify the [configuration file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.10.0/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml) to include the following before applying it:

```
...
spec:
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          operator: Exists
          effect: NoSchedule
        - operator: Exists
          effect: NoSchedule
      ...
```

This was an issue for my clusters when upgrading from k8s v1.10. Looks to be related to [changing taints/tolerations in different k8s versions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#taints-and-tolerations).